# Replace default preinstalled Google apps safely

Tags: google-play-store, adb, android-10, redmi

I have a Redmi 9C with Android 10, it came with several pre-installed apps from Google and Redmi, I used ADB to un-installed some apps that I thought was safe, but for some reason, some of those apps came back without a system upgrade (that I'm aware of), and the developer options that I had set up previously was wiped out. I'm not that familiar with Android, so please bear with me, here are my questions:

1. can I replace safely "essential apps" (such as phone, SMS, downloader, etc.) with alternative ones? I was a Windows user until Windows 10, then switched to Linux after MS started doing OS upgrade on the background without user's permission, it seems Google is start doing the same, is there a site with updated/reliable info about this topic?
2. is there a tip/trick to "not allow" Google to re-install those apps that I removed? Why only some of the apps came back and not the others? Maybe because the apps I'm still using needs some libraries from the apps that I removed? For instance I can't remove Google Pay form ADB (it's not listed there), and I've removed Google Wallet, now Wallet is back again and not showing in ADB!

ps: 1) ADB - I'm using [Xiaomi ADB/Fastboot Tools 7.0.3](https://github.com/Szaki/XiaomiADBFastbootTools/releases/), it's a jar file with UI frontend, so I'm not using command line.
2) My bad, did not write down the package name, will do next time/next packages.

Comment: Please include the command(s) you have used for "uninstalling". Google Wallet is the new name of Google Pay.

Comment: The packageName of an app can be totally different from the app name displayed on the Andrroid UI (because the app packageName can later not be changed). To get a list of packageNames and how to get the app display name is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650765/get-application-name-label-via-adb-shell-or-terminal

Comment: thanks for the tips, I've updated my post.

Comment: As long as you have the Google Core apps (especially Google Services Framework) on the device, Google has the possibility to do such things. Depending on how far you wish to go, there are things like "unofficial installers" for microG which do the replacements (replacing the GSF by the open-source microG framework (I'm not sure which of those did take care of GSF removal, but vaguely remember there was one; [microg-unofficial-installer](https://github.com/micro5k/microg-unofficial-installer) only describes what it installs so it might not work with GSF present).

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, I'll take a look at microG and tutorial on ADB commands (it seems the UI is outdated and not reporting properly the installed apps.)